# Unexpected end-of-input in user.rb - referencing another file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to get omniauth-facebook and devise to jive with each other in my user model. When I run `$ rails s` I receive the error

```
    /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:424:in `load': /Users/maxnied/Desktop/vital_app/app/models/user.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:424:in `block in load_file'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:616:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `load_file'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require_or_load'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in `load_missing_constant'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:535:in `get'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `constantize'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:297:in `get'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `new'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `add_mapping'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:221:in `block in devise_for'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `each'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `devise_for'
from /Users/maxnied/Desktop/vital_app/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `eval_block'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:319:in `draw'
from /Users/maxnied/Desktop/vital_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/maxnied/Desktop/vital_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /Users/maxnied/Desktop/vital_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Users/maxnied/Desktop/vital_app/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/maxnied/Desktop/vital_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
from /Users/maxnied/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

source from user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
  has_one  :contact_info
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
  has_and_belongs_to_many :regions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_many :managed_campaigns, class_name: Campaign, foreign_key: :owner_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_info

  validates_associated :contact_info, message: "is not complete"

  delegate :full_name, to: :contact_info

  def facebook
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication 
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name  
      user.image = auth.info.image 
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not seeing the missing end in the syntax, although I fully admit I'm pretty new with the language and would be surprised if I did. I've systematically commented out each part of the source, as well as all of the existing ends (and added additional ones at the end). The only thing that works is commenting out `def facebook' to the end. A friend suggested checking my routes.rb file, but again I'm not familiar enough with the syntax to discern if that's the issue. routes.rb below:

```
VitalApp::Application.routes.draw do
```

devise_for :user, has_one: :contact_info#, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "user/omniauth_callbacks" }
    devise_scope :user do
      get    "register", to: "devise/registrations#new"
      get    "login",    to: "devise/sessions#new"
      delete "logout",   to: "devise/sessions#destroy"
    end
    root "home#index"
    resources :campaigns
    end

any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `end` of `def facebook` method

Comment: if this has worked for you then kindly accept the answer